# PDFTK random order

Tags: linux, unix, pdf, random, pdftk

I'm using the unix [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) package to merge multiple pdf documents together into a single file with the terminal.

```
pdftk *.pdf cat output merged.pdf
```

This merges the pdf files correctly but ordered on name. I'd like to 'shuffle' this and order the different pdf's random. the different files have to be randomly ordered. But the pages inside each file have to be ordered correctly.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: `The pdf's pages have to be in order, just the order of the different files has to be random.` what do you mean exactly?

Comment: the different files have to be randomly ordered. But the pages inside each file have to be ordered correctly.

Comment: I know I could rename all files inside the folder to random numbers and merge that. But it seems like a bad way of doing so. The package accepts multiple input files so it would be better to write a script that randomises the input parameters like so: `pdftk file3.pdf file1.pdf file4.pdf file2.pdf cat output merged.pdf`

Comment: The `shuf` command may do what you want, as long as the file names don't contain newline or blanks.